# Is com.sun.jdic and Flexdoc library still in use in java ? can we integrate with AAD?

Tags: java, azure, azure-active-directory, jnlp

I'm referring to an old Java application, almost 10 years old.
My application uses technology components like Java Webstart component (JNLP), FlexDock ( Java Docking for native UI library ), jdic, etc.

For authentication, this application directly using login credentials. Want to upgrade to Azure Active Directory.

Can we accommodate Azure AD functionality in such an application?
is anyone have any reference document or something?

Answer (score 0):

JDIC is obsolete technology and the project was "abandoned" 12+ years ago.

There is a copy of the source code tree sitting on [Github](https://github.com/gelosie/jdic) but the original website (java.net) that where the project material, mailing lists and so on once lives is long gone.

Flexdock (not Flexdoc) is also available on [Github](https://github.com/opencollab/flexdock).  It also appears to be inactive.  (The last commit was in 2018.)

However, it appears that [SciLab](https://www.scilab.org) depends on Flexdock, so there is still some life in the project.

---

Can you integrate JDIC and/or Flexdock with AAD?

Frankly, I don't know.

But I would suggest that you are better off removing all dependencies on JDIC.  Or, if that is too much effort, maybe you should consider ditching your 10+ year old legacy application.